# REGEX needs to ignore directory up (..)

Tags: regex

Hey guys I ran into an error with my regex that needs to be fixed

when I hit a .. in url, I'm getting a match and I shouldn't

here is the regex

```
~\b(?::url|:\surl)\s*\(\s*(["\']?+)\K(?:/(?!/)|(?=[\s>]|\1))~i
```

I thought it should be

```
~\b(?::url|:\surl)\s*\(\s*(["\']?+)\K(?:/(?!/|..)|(?=[\s>]|\1))~i
```

but that doesn't seem to work?

Things it should match

```
background:url('/foo.jpg') repeat-y top center;
background:url("/foo.jpg") repeat-y top center;
background:url(/foo.jpg) repeat-y top center;

background:url('foo.jpg') repeat-y top center;
background:url("foo.jpg") repeat-y top center;
background:url(foo.jpg) repeat-y top center;

background: url('/foo.jpg') repeat-y top center;
background: url("/foo.jpg") repeat-y top center;
background: url(/foo.jpg) repeat-y top center;
```

Should not match but does (and does)

```
background:url('../foo.jpg') repeat-y top center;
background:url("../foo.jpg") repeat-y top center;
background:url(../foo.jpg) repeat-y top center;

background: url('../foo.jpg') repeat-y top center;
background: url("../foo.jpg") repeat-y top center;
background: url(../foo.jpg) repeat-y top center;
```

and using `(?!/|\.\.)` still seems to match

Comment: can you add the string it matches but it should not?

Comment: Need to escape `.` --> `\.`, since it is a special character in regex.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out, my exclusion needed to behind my look back

```
~\b(?::url|:\surl)\s*\(\s*(["\']?+)(?:(?!\.\./))\K(?:/(?!/)|(?=[\s>]|\1))~i
```